# get the data type of columns in a select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I know that you can get the type of a table's columns using the query below.

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'myTbl'
```

I was wondering if when you write a select query which involves 2 tables or more whether you can do something similar? I.e. is there a way to determine the column data types?

Comment: You _could_ potentially use dynamic SQL and setup a union query where the first row for each column in the result set is the type.  But, more typically you would just inspect the table structure and query as you would normally.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4868/1186 and also see https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views and https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/20/sql-server-v-next-denali-metadata-enhancements

Answer (score 6):

Just another option is `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set()`

The nice thing about this is you can supply *virtually* any query, table, view, or even a stored procedure.

**Example**

```
Select column_ordinal
      ,name
      ,system_type_name 
 From sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Exec [dbo].[prc-App-Lottery-Search] ''7613''',null,null )
```

**Returns**

```
column_ordinal  name        system_type_name
1               DrawDate    date
2               DrawDE      varchar(1)
3               DrawAct     varchar(4)
4               DrawNrm     varchar(4)
5               Hits        int
6               Elapsed     nvarchar(4000)
```

**Generic Example to see all columns available**

```
Select *
 From sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Select * from master..spt_values',null,null )
```

Comment: * unless the query or stored procedure references a temp table, crosses database/server boundaries, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I should have said VIRTUALLY :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME IN ('myTbl1','myTbl2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below query to know all details about the columns in the table (shorter than selecting all columns)

> describe tableName;